# Git - Uploading to a specific folder in a repo

Tags: git

I am learning git and I am trying to upload a file into a specific folder within a repository. I don't want it on the main page when you access the repo but a folder within it.

Is this possible?

Tutorial I followed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fTdrqaouzPI

Code I put:

```
git init
git add <folder1> <folder2> <etc.>
git commit -m "Your message about the commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/yourUsername/yourRepository.git
git push -u origin master
git push origin master
```

I tried to change the github link in "git remote add origin [https://github.com/yourUsername/yourRepository.git"](https://github.com/yourUsername/yourRepository.git%22) to "git remote add origin [https://github.com/yourUsername/yourRepository/folder.git"](https://github.com/yourUsername/yourRepository/folder.git%22) but that doesn't seem to work as I get a "fatal" error.

Comment: "https://github.com/yourUsername/yourRepository.git"" is correct. What happened when you ran the original commands. What error did you get?

Comment: It worked fine originally. My question is: Can I go 1 level deeper and into a specific folder I have. Not just the main area.

i.e https://github.com/yourUsername/yourRepository/folder.git

Comment: What do you mean by "1 level deeper"? You can create whatever folders and files you want and nest them however you wish. You use `git add` and `git commit` to commit them to the repo and `git push` to upload them to GitHub. You don't need to change the URL for the remote for any of this.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to understand here is that the folder with your project on your own computer **is a git repsoitory**. To add files to a folder in that repository, you just create the folder and files, then use `git add` and `git commit` to commit them to your repo. `git push` then will upload the entire history of your commits to the remote. You can add whatever folders and files you want this way. They can be nested in whatever structure you want.

The second thing to understand is that git does not track folders. It only tracks files.

To understand git better, I recommend reading [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2). It has great examples for each command. The first three chapters cover 90% of what you need to work with git on your projects.